# How can I configure GNU Make to pass exported variables to the shell function?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've bumped up against an unexpected oddity in GNU Make and can't find a way to configure it sanely. I'm assigning `SHELL` to a custom shell of my own design, but the problem with what variables are exported is readily reproducibly with a simple bash shell:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

export FOO := bar

.PHONY: all a b c

all: a b

a:
    @echo A: $$(env | grep FOO)

b:
    @echo B: $(shell env | grep FOO)

c:
    @echo === main target ===
    @echo $$(env | sed -e 's/=.*//')
    @echo === shell function ===
    @echo $(shell env | sed -e 's/=.*//')
```

This produces a somewhat unexpected result:

```
$ make
A: FOO=bar
B:
$ FOO=baz make
A: FOO=bar
B: FOO=baz
```

As documented in [communicating variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html#Variables_002fRecursion) the exported `FOO` variable is exposed as an environment variable to the shell that runs lines in a recipe. What is unexpected is that the
[shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html#Shell-Function) does not get the same treatment! In fact a quick look at what turns up in `make c` there are several variables that just don't get passed through. I could work around this for every variable by manually passing it in (e.g. `$(shell FOO="$(FOO)" env)`) but that gets silly (and dangerous) fast.

This is particularly problematic because the variable I was hoping to export is `PATH`. The fact that shells building my targets have one `PATH`‌ variable while anything is run in a shell function has a different `PATH` is problematic. If you look at the complete env

How can I‌ mark some variables from my `Makefile` environment so that they get automatically passed as part of the environment to shells run from the shell function?

Comment: You can't.  No make-exported values are ever passed to the `shell` function.

Comment: Buggers. @MadScientist Is there a way to set a different `SHELL` value for targets vs. the shell function?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.  You can specify a different value for `SHELL` using target-specific variables... is that what you want?

Comment: @MadScientist I realize I can change the per-target value for `SHELL`, but that changes both the shell used to run the recipe *and* the shell used to run `$(shell ...)`  functions. I was hoping to change them independently...one for running recipes and one for functions. I could use that to bootstrap all my shell functions with the necessary environment.

Comment: There is no way to control which shell is invoked by `$(shell ...)` separately from the shell invoked for recipes.

Comment: **WARNING**: This seems to have changed in [version4.4](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?10593). I ended up having code that worked around this and even assumed it would be the case, which of course has blown up.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @MadScientist, the `$(shell ...)` is not passed exported variables. Depending on the situation, if the number of environment variables is known, possible to use explicit variables to the shell command. e.g.

```
c:
    @echo === shell function ===
    @echo $(shell FOO=$FOO env | sed -e 's/=.*//')
```

Of course, this solution assumes that the it is possible to enumerate all the variables to be passed down, and that the number of variables is reasonably small, otherwise the code will get ugly.

As an alternative, consider using a temporary file, instead of make values to pass values

```
c:
    # env var are set, store result in var.txt
    do-something > var.txt
    # Uses the result of the previous step, from var.txt
    step2 $$(cat var.txt)
```

Comment: This was true up until GNU Make 4.4 came out, now the behavior has changed.

Answer (score -1):

What the Shell function does is parse the output and expand the variables it finds in it. Consider the following code:

```
export BANANA = I am a banana
foo: G := $(shell echo who am I? '$$'BANANA)
foo:
    @echo $(G)
```

Output: who am I? I am a banana

Comment: Ha! You've tied yourself in a knot and not even noticed. This does not actually solve the problem I  describe in the question. What you've managed to do is convince the `echo` inside of the `$(shell ...)` function to echo a string with literal `$` sign. At the time that shell runs it does not actually have access to an environment variable `BANANA`. You are getting that output because the literal string with the $ sign in it is being passed to the second echo in the recipe for *foo*, and that is the shell that also happens to be able to see your exported variable and hence can expand it.